# I have this query to get statistics, but it takes more than 10 seconds to return results from 1M records. how I can optimize it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query to get statistics, but it takes more than 10 seconds to return results from 1M records. So how I can optimize it?

This is my query:

```
select "Ministry", 
        "Department",
        count(*),
        null, 
        concat(E'\'',string_agg("AccountNumber",E'\',\'' ),E'\'' ) 
from public."Employees" 
group by "Ministry","Department"
```

I am using PostgreSQL database

The result should be returned like this:

```
Ministry  Department    Count   AccountNumber 
 x          x1            3      1,899,3
 b          b1            4      5,21,1,7
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, timing, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. But as you are doing this for all rows in the table, there is not much you can do

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no where criteria, you could create an index with the fields Ministry, Department and AccountNumber.

The RDBMS can then use an [index-only-scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-index-only-scans.html)(easier grouping, less data) instead of a table scan.